# What would it happens if I update snappy core from a earlier version?

Tags: ubuntu-core

Due to some reasons, I just rollback my snappy ubuntu core from 16 to 15, I'd like to know what's my lastest core version if version 17 released and I do snappy update again. Is version 15 or 16? (15 is my active core version)

```
(amd64)ubuntu@localhost:~$ snappy list -v
Name                 Date       Version      Developer
ubuntu-core          2016-02-17 15           ubuntu*
ubuntu-core          2016-02-25 16           ubuntu
webdm                2015-12-23 0.11         canonical*
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run:
`snappy list -u`. This will show you an asterisk next to the package name if a new update is available.

Then, you can just upgrade as you usually do and you should be fine (or let the autoupdate do its work).

Comment: So you mean even I do not perform snappy update by myself, the auto update would do the work?